# How do copy application files to docker container when starting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that

- contains all runtimes needed for my app to run.
- does not contain the application

The idea is, that I don't need to rebuild the image in order to deploy new version of my app.

How do I copy files (my application binaries) from host to container when starting the container?

##### My Attempt

when I run `docker run -it -e CopyBinFrom=c:\pathToBinaries` myimage

the folder c:\pathToBinaries is not copied into the container

dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
ENV CopyBinFrom=. 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM base AS app_base

# ignores value from docker run
COPY $CopyBinFrom ./ 

ENTRYPOINT ["cmd"]
```

Comment: You can use a volume for that, example : `-v $(pwd):/app`. Your env variable does only work when building the image, not when running the container. And since you copy the files, they will not be up to date with the latest changes and you will need to make a new image to update it, which is not what you want. A volume however is mounting your source files when running the container and it will be up to date, and any change will be reflected inside the container.

Comment: So is the mounting recommended way? It is a two way synchronization, so I'm afraid that if I scale the containers (many instances of the same app) it will conflict, e.g. lock files on the host, or overwrite some configs, etc..

Comment: the good way is to create an image with your application file, using dockerfile. So no trouble to scale up. In development mode you can mount application files.

Comment: Why is building a new image bad?  There are several advantages, like not needing the source code when you go to deploy it, and being able to easily roll back by recreating a container from an older tag.  It seems like the path you're describing isn't really different from just installing the language runtime on the target system; it would work, but I wouldn't consider it the best way to use Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I will reconsider building new image in my CD pipeline. However, my release pipeline already supports rolling back to previous version (copying app executables and configs from artifacts repository). I use windows containers to isolate different processes on the server, so they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: You are confusing `docker run` with `docker build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [layer caching](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/) you have no "rebuilt overhead". There is no need for mounting files somehow.
If you want to use your executable(s) directly then just use a [dockerfile](/questions/tagged/dockerfile) like this (almost already yours).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

COPY executable.exe ./ 

# not sure if that is correct
ENTRYPOINT ["executable.exe"]
```

With that you can just run `docker build . -t yourApp:yourTag`.
When you run this command twice, then you will see that the second run will be much faster. For that you have to use a [docker-tag](/questions/tagged/docker-tag).

Pros:

- Scaling is no problem
- Sharing images is no problem
- Better isolation between containers
- Easy to understand

Reminder: [docker-container](/questions/tagged/docker-container) are not virtual machines. They should not be used like this.

Comment: Assuming I run `docker build` in CD pipeline let's say 15 times a day, won't the docker host get overwhelmed with tons of unused containers soon?

Comment: You mean images. The answer is yes and no. You can use identical image-names and -tags, then they will be always overwritten. If not, then there are many repositories, which can delete your old and used images (like Artifactory).

Comment: If I use same image names/tags, then I can't deploy the image to multiple stages (test, uat, production), can I?

Comment: You can give multiple names/tags at once. Like `abc:prod` and `abc:test`. But it is more usual with version numbers like `abc:v1.2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do copy application files to docker container when starting

Your dockerfile looks good.

Try to troubleshoot the issue this way:

1/ You can check whether the `CopyBinFrom` environment variable was being passed to the container correctly or not. This command's output will show the `CopyBinFrom` environment variable value.

```
docker run -it -e CopyBinFrom=c:\pathToBinaries -v c:\pathToBinaries:/app myimage
```

2/ Also you should be sure that the `c:\pathToBinaries` folder exists on the host machine. Otherwise, create it.

3/ Furthermore you should be sure that the `myimage` image has the necessary permissions to access the `c:\pathToBinaries folder`. The output of this command should show the `c:\pathToBinaries` folder.

You can do it this way:

```
docker run -it --security-opt label=disable userns=true myimage ls -la /c
```

Comment: Not sure what the COPY statement with environment variable is supposed to do

Comment: what's the point of COPY if you mount it anyway when running it ?